# coldfusion - short way of displaying text of a specific node

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I am building a table with the results of a XML returned response. Inside the table I have this line of code to return the value of "BusinessName" node:

```
<td>
#xmlreturned.MyCompany.body.productSelectionResponse.businessDataReport.CompanySummary.Identification.BusinessDetails.BusinessName.XmlText#
</td>
```

My only issue is that I have more than 100 of these lines and the first part is always repeating such as: "xmlreturned.MyCompany.body.productSelectionResponse.businessDataReport.CompanySummary.Identification."
So my question is, is there a way to shorten this line of code that has a lot of repetitive wording?
Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question to show starting value and desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a variable.

```
<cfset Company = xmlreturned.MyCompany.body.productSelectionResponse.businessDataReport.CompanySummary.Identification>

...

<td>#HTMLEditFormat(Company.BusinessDetails.BusinessName.XmlText)#</td>
```

Never output data to HTML without using either `HTMLEditFormat()` (wich works perfectly fine) or one of the specialized functions that are available from ColdFusion 10 onwards (see documentation: [Security enhancements in ColdFusion 10 - XSS Attack](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d3185183e145c0d1353e31f559-7fff.html)).

Related reading: [Ben Nadel's blog: For Better Security Use HtmlEditFormat() In Conjunction With JSStringFormat() In ColdFusion](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2570-for-better-security-use-htmleditformat-in-conjunction-with-jsstringformat-in-coldfusion.htm)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but it's not working. So what I am doing is send a request for a xml feed and I store the response xml into xmlreturned :
<cfset xmlreturned=xmlparse(cfhttp.filecontent)>
So now the xmlreturned variable containes the whole XML file from which I want to display parts of it in a table as showed in the description.

Comment: I've tested it, it works. (Also, "not working" is not an error description. "not working" means anything and nothing. Be precise.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Tomalak :) . I just went back to the code and analysed what wasn't working and found the mistake I was making. I am new at coldfusion so... It's all working perfectly :) 
Thank you!

Comment: I thought it must be something simple. :)

Comment: I was creating the variable outside my cfif condition so before asking for the XML file :| rookie mistake

Comment: Making mistakes is the only way to learn. Break it, fix it, break it, fix it, get a bit better every time.